# c# api to salesforce

Tags: api, c#

My app does queries to the SF, after a select I got some objects, when I do this:

```
string id = Object.Id;
User a = Object.CreatedBy;
```

I can see how the "id" variable give me the Id of the record without problems, but when arrives to the "CreatedBy" it gives me "null".

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what was your query?